# Flutter: Create custom dialog as StatefulWidget?

Tags: flutter, dialog, widget, textinput, stateful

I'm working on an app that will get only 2 inputs from the user, maybe 3 in the future. So I use showDialog with 2 inputfield and 2 buttons. Very simple. Looks pretty much like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkkUg.png)
It shows up perfectly in the main screen if it's being called as a function. But I would like to use that same dialog in another screen in the app and just change the text on one of the buttons. Since the dialog code it's long and I don't want to repeat it, I want to put it in a new StatefulWidget (to retrieve the information from the input fields and clear them afterwards). Now the problem is that **I can't find a way to return the dialog from an external widget.** I don't know if it's actually impossible because of the whole async Widget incompatibility or I'm just too stupid to figure this out.

This is the code for my dialog (as a function):

```
_dialog() async {
  await showDialog<String>(
    context: context,
    child: ButtonBarTheme(
      data: ButtonBarThemeData(alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center),
      child: AlertDialog(
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        content: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
              child: new TextField(
                // onSubmitted: next,
                autofocus: true,
                controller: _title,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 2),
                  labelText: 'Title',
                  hintText: 'Example: New Smartphone',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            TextField(
              autofocus: true,
              controller: _codigo,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                labelText: 'Code',
                hintText: 'Example: EC20008347607',
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        actions: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 35, bottom: 5),
                child: FlatButton(
                    color: Colors.cyan[600],
                    child: const Text('CANCEL'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    }),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, bottom: 5),
                child: FlatButton(
                  color: Colors.cyan[600],
                  child: const Text('ADD'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _title.text = '';
                      _code.text = '';
                    });
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help. I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in another dart file that accepts any property values that aren't static, like this:

```
CustomAlertDialog({String leftButtonText, String rightButtonText}) async {
  return AlertDialog(
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        content: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
              child: new TextField(
                // onSubmitted: next,
                autofocus: true,
                controller: _title,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 2),
                  labelText: 'Title',
                  hintText: 'Example: New Smartphone',
                ),
              ),
            ),
             TextField(
              autofocus: true,
              controller: _codigo,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                labelText: 'Code',
                hintText: 'Example: EC20008347607',
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        actions: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 35, bottom: 5),
                child: FlatButton(
                    color: Colors.cyan[600],
                    child: const Text('$leftButtonText'),
                    onPressed: () {
                       Navigator.pop(context);
                    }),
              ),
               Container(
                 padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, bottom: 5),
                child: FlatButton(
                  color: Colors.cyan[600],
                  child: const Text('$rightButtonText'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _title.text = '';
                      _code.text = '';
                    });
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried earlier returning an AlertDialog but VSCode says "Missing concrete implementation of 'State.build'". I need it to be in a stateful widget in order to use TextControllers to extract the data from the input fields. And in any way I tried to return a Dialog from a Widget (with the build state) I get the error because dialogs are async operations. Thanks for the response anyway.

Comment: You either have to pass in the current BuildContext.  I forgot to add that.

Comment: Doesn't work. I tried to add that code to a Stateful widget and pass the BuildContext. VS Code says there's no error unlike my other implementation, But the dialog doesn't show up either. I think it's pointless. Dialogs are supposed to use to show simple things to users, maybe retrieve some information like in my case, but they're not meant to be fully external components, As far as could check, the only way they show up  it's with the trigger function on the same screen they overlay, so I'll have to repeat the code.  Thanks anyway. 

Comment: Or, you could use a state management system like RxDart or BLoC.  That would allow you to manage the 2 fields without depending on a stateful widget.  I was able to do that with a snackbar, with operates the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I think we have to build our widget from the ground up as there is no dialog box that exposes the state. Hope this helps:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html

Answer (score 0):

Try my code snippet

**

```
MaterialButton(
              color: Colors.blue,
              height: 50,
              shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
              ),
              textColor: Colors.white,
              child:  Text('Show Info Dialog',),
              onPressed: () {
                SimpleDialogs.showinfoDialog(context: context, title: "Something insert here");
              },
```

Comment: "Asked 1 year, 6 months ago". I finished this app a long time ago and I didn't even implemented this.

Comment: @lenny73: when you finished the app shouldn't matter since this site isn't a help site per se but rather a question-and-answer repository, and an answer that attempts to answer your original question, one that future visitors may come to looking for solutions, is a good thing.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31366563)